# Number of orders of distances between points on a line

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, permutations

Points $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ on a line form a set from $n(n-1)/2$ distances between them. Suppose all that distances are different, numerating them from the shortest to the longest one we obtain some permutation on $n(n-1)/2$ elements.

**How many permutations can be obtained by this way?**

Comment: In other words, you want to count the number of regions in the hyperplane arrangement $\{x_i-x_j,x_i+x_j-x_k-x_l\}$ (and divide it by $n!$). I doubt that a formula exists.

Comment: Can you do it for a few small values of $n$, Arseniy, and then consult the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I will try if I found how to program it.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, what about the asymptotic?

Comment: immediate upper estimate is like $n^{3n+o(n)}$, is it ok for you?

Comment: Is it by any chance http://oeis.org/A004123 ?

Comment: Have you had a look at that link, Arseniy?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the ref. I do not understand why it could be the same. But I am busy on that week and will look on it later